# unable to remove the specific row from a table through jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i m using jquery to add new row and delete them but my problem is that when i click on minus button it start deleting the row from bottom to up and not delete the particular row.means if i filled the data in 10 rows and now want to delete the 5th row then on cliking minus button on 5th row it removes 10th, 9th and so on...and i want that only  5th row will bdeletedhow could it will b possible.

Here is my jquery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#add").click(function() {
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
        var last_sn = $('#mytable tbody>tr:last>td:first').html();
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last>td:first').html(parseInt(last_sn) + 1);
        return false;
    });
    $('#minus').click(function() {
        $('#mytable tr:last-child').remove();
    });
});​
```

Comment: Have you tried this? $(this).remove();

Comment: i have a similar working sample from other question here: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/bYBPD/ see if it can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('#mytable tr:last-child').remove(); will allways remove the last row.

If you have several minus buttons then you should not use the same id (#minus) use a class instead.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k8dAs/

```
$('.minus').click(function()
{
  $(this).parents("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: i just want to ask that is it possible that the S.No.will also change means if i delet the 5th row the 6th row will becam row no 5(S.No. 5)

Comment: Dont know if I really understand your question, but the minus button will allways work since it deletes the table row it is existing in...

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
$('#minus').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});​
```

Your code `$('#mytable tr:last-child').remove();` will always remove the last row.
Also, you should make `minus` a class instead since it will be replicated for multiple rows leading to multiple elements with same `id`.

Answer (score 0):

This `$('#mytable tr:last-child').remove();` should be

```
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
```

Comment: i just want to ask that is it possible that the S.No.will also change means if i delet the 5th row the 6th row will becam row no 5(S.No. 5)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `S.No.`. But when you `.remove()` a row, the HTML index of the `tr` after the one removed will change.